# can't add time and duration

Tags: ros-lunar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am basing myself on [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/274345/publish-on-a-topic-for-a-certain-time/) to do some time manipulation in ros. But when I write :

```
ros::Time beginTime = ros::Time::now();                                                                                                                  
ros::Duration delta_t = ros::Duration(t/2);                                                                                                              
ros::Time t1 = delta_t + beginTime;                                                                                                                      
ros::Time t2 = delta_t + t1;
```

I get the error

```
error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘ros::Duration’ and ‘ros::Time’)
ros::Time t1 = delta_t + beginTime;
```

Why is that? Something has changed since the other post?

Thank you for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303703/can%27t-add-time-and-duration./) by [edamondo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33620/edamondo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2018-09-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On Melodic the time has to come before the duration:

```
ros::Time t1 = beginTime + delta_t;
ros::Time t2 = t1 + delta_t;
```

http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Time#Time_and_Duration_Arithmetic shows the proper order (but doesn't say the opposite won't work).

The other post says the code is untested, so the ordering requirement may or may not have changed.

(Update- I fixed the other post to have the correct time + duration ordering)

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2018-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amjack](https://answers.ros.org/users/57146/amjack/) on 2022-02-25**:
worked for me on ROS noetic! Thanks